# Is there a nice way to solve this circular dependency situation?

Tags: maven, dependency-management, circular-dependency, bamboo

I have a large project, let's call it *proj*, with a bunch of sub-projects, let's call those *subproj_1* to *subproj_n*.

I also have a separate project called *tool*.

*tool* depends on *subproj_1*.

*subproj_2* depends on *tool* (in test scope only).

Our CI platform is Bamboo.

Comment: Could you add further details? From your description there is no circular dependency

Comment: well, there is and there is not -- I can build subproj1, tool, subproj2.   But in reality the way builds go is that you want to build the entire proj, right?  And that fails because tool is not built yet.  And I can't build tool before I build proj.  So manually this is all buildable and once build for new version succeeds it is all good, but after version bump we need to do some manual building which feels dirty.

Comment: If this means it only fails cause tool is not build means for me you have missed a correct dependency to tool...If you have a dependency only in test scope this means for me factor out the part which is in test scope into separate module which should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A common pattern to break a circular dependency is to pull out the parts of the code that causing the circular dependency to a new common subproject, remove the dependencies between the existing subprojects and add a dependency to the new subproject.

If you do not want to create a new module you can refactor the shared parts of the code to on of the existing subprojects and update the dependencies so that they are unidirectional.